# AdMob simple tutorial doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, admob, adview

I'm in an early process of developping a game for Android and I'm trying to incorporate an ad banner using AdMob. I have downloaded the sample straight from the tutorial on the official [site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals#addadview), so I guess that whatever I'm doing wrong here has to be basic since it crushes after a few seconds when debugging on my Galaxy S2 device. Pleae help.

```
package com.google.example.ads.fundamentals;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
 */
public class BannerSample extends Activity {

  private AdView adView;
  private final TelephonyManager tm =
      (TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

  private final String AD_MOB_ID = "my AdMob ID goes here";

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AD_MOB_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(tm.getDeviceId());

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

The Logcat data in a screen shot is [here](http://oi48.tinypic.com/350s8yf.jpg)

Edit: Also adding the Manifest.XML, which I suspect is what causeing the problems - amazingly the one that came with the example from the official site had an error in it (according to Eclipse), so I had to modify it a bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
              android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloAdMobActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have any logcat information about the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so it turns out the problem is with `tm.getDeviceId()`, which for whatever reason caused the program to crush.

Answer (score 1):

Logcat information would be super useful, but I'm betting on one of these two reasons:

1. You referenced the SDK as an external Jar, and didn't add it into your `libs/` folder.  You have two options here to fix this: add it to your `libs/` folder, or go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export and check the AdMob jar.
2. You don't have a LinearLayout in your XML with `android:id="linearLayout"`.  This is less likely as the sample project should include this.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I checked the AdMob jar in Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export and I do have a LinearLayout with the id in my XML like you said. Unfortunately it still crushes. The app loads with what appears to be a banner with "Android-Fundamentals" text in it on a blue background that disappears withing a few seconds. Then the app crushes with an "Unfortunately AndroidFundamentals has stopped" pop up. Also if I try to hit the 'back' button it doesn't respond and crushes the same after a few seconds.

Comment: I would love to give you more info, but I don't know what else to add - I did exactly as the tutorial suggested.

Comment: sorry, I attached the Logcat to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```